# pybind11 same class name different namespce in different functions

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

New to pybind11, hope someone can help with questions.

I'm wrapping, in two different hpp files (p.hpp and s.hpp), two classes which both have a class  member (same name, with different namespace).

```
h.hpp:
void initP(py::module_ &m)
{
 using pn = a::b::p;
 py::class<pn> pnclass(m, "pn");
 pnclass.def("func1", &pn::func1);

 py::class<ps> psclass(m, "ps");
 psclass.def_readonly("pn", &ps::pn);   //member pn (a::b::p), because it is inside initP(), correct?
}

s.hpp: 

void initS(py::module_ &m(
{
  using pn = a::c::p;
  py::class<pn> pnclass(m, "pn");
  pnclass.def("func2", &pn::func2);

  py::class<cs> psclass(m, "cs");
  psclass.def_readonly("ps", &cs::pn);   //member pn (a::c::p), since inside initS(), correct?
}
```

In case the usage of the two pn():

The both two of pn() will be exposed, correct?
So it means the one who writes python code, needs to know which pnclass should be used to call func1 and func2, correct?

I checked the pybind11 document, but not sure where to find the relative info.

Appreicate it if anyone can share it.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot define two extension classes with the same name `"pn"` in a single extension module, so your python coder should be able to distinguish them according to which module they are imported from.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have to rename it.